# Use of Kotlin tag in Android questions

Tags: discussion, tags

I removed the kotlin tag from two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47225423/display-class-picker-in-android-library), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47224716/android-separate-multiple-phonebooks)) today, because I considered that they are no Kotlin related, a Java answer would be acceptable too. Adding the tag could prevent users from reading the actual question.

Anyway, I'm asking me if this actions were fine. When I should apply a Kotlin tag to a Android question? It's fine to add Kotlin tag for every Android question I post just because I prefer a Kotlin based answer?

Comment: Honestly I want to help fix some of those edits, but the first question *really* doesn't look like it's worth saving...

Comment: Isn't it simple? You apply the Kotlin tag when you want to focus on  Kotlin rather than Java? I don't think either question is of particularly high quality though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should only modify the tags if you are certain.

In these questions, the users have tagged it Kotlin and they apparently want answers that are applicable to Kotlin. Removing that tag goes against the OP's intentions.

Adding a tag, also, should only be done if it is in line with the OP's intentions. If the OP does *not* tag it with Kotlin, and any code sample in the question isn't Kotlin... then we can safely assume that they're not using Kotlin. *You* may want to have an answer in Kotlin, but the OP does not.

If there is good reason to assume that the OP is using Kotlin, then you can add that tag.

If there is good reason to assume that the OP is not using Kotlin, then you can remove that tag.

Comment: Then the kotlin tag MUST be never removed  from a android question (?)

Comment: @crgarridos The kotlin framework is valid and fully supported by the android system so why would the tag ever need to be removed? https://kotlinlang.org/

Comment: @JoeW I got the point, because of that I asked for. I think for iOS happen the same. Thanks